# HTACCESS change subdomain, add a custom file extension and url parameters

Tags: htaccess

I'm trying to redirect this url:

```
www.example.com/path/index.php?user=username&option=optname
```

to

```
username.example.com/path/optname.html
```

I tried several ways but I'm getting errors. How to do that?

Comment: Add the code you have tried to your question. What error are you getting? If you access `username.example.com/path/optname.html` directly does it work OK? "add a custom file extension and url parameters" - You state "add" in the title, but it looks like you want to "remove" these in your example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the sample rewrite commands you should be looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.net/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```